# What is the difference between AbstractRestfulController and AbstractActionController?

Tags: php, zend-framework2

What is the difference from a practical point of view of using AbstractRestfulController over AbstractActionController to implement controller classes? Does the AbstractRestfulController only allows RESTful behaviour? Is there a side-by-side comparison somewhere?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

ZF2's `AbstractRestfulController` provides an interface for quick and painless implementation of basic HTTP methods (e.g. GET, POST, PUT, DELETE), while still allowing the use of controller actions.  `AbstractActionController` is intended for use with controller actions.

First, only a single route is required, regardless of how many of the native HTTP methods are implemented in that particular controller.  Below is an example route configuration:

```
'api_customer' => [
    'type' => 'Segment',
    'options' => [
        'route' => '/customer/:id',
        'constraints' => [
            'id' => '[0-9]+',
        ],
        'defaults' => [
            '__NAMESPACE__' => 'Customer\Controller',
            'controller' => 'Index',
        ],
    ],
],
```

And lastly, the controller implementation is rather straightforward (and should be somewhat familiar).

```
<?php
class CustomerController extends AbstractRestfulController
{
    public function get($id)
    {
        // associated with GET request with identifier
    }

    public function getList()
    {
        // associated with GET request without identifier
    }

    public function create($data)
    {
        // associated with POST request
    }

    public function update($id, $data)
    {
        // associated with PUT request
    }

    public function delete($id)
    {
        // associated with DELETE request
    }
}
```

For more information, I recommend a quick look at the manual. http://framework.zend.com/manual/current/en/modules/zend.mvc.controllers.html#the-abstractrestfulcontroller